# Find the id of the first instance of a class

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I have a few `input`'s... Some with classes, some without. The classes are arbitrarily assigned (with "`.error`", on a failed form submit, to give you an idea).

**How do I find the id of the first instance where that class appears?**

For example:

```
<input id="firstName" type="text" name="firstName" class="text" value="" />
<input id="lastName" type="text" name="lastName" class="text error" value="" />
<input id="email" type="text" name="email" class="text" value="" />
<select name="gender" class="error">
    <option value=""></option>
    <option value="male">Male</option>
    <option value="female">Female</option>                          
</select>
```

As you'll note, there is also an `error` class on the `select` tag. So, in this particular case I need to find the id "lastName" since it is the first time that an element appears with the class "error".

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$('.error').first();` will return the first element with class error.

Comment: Thanks. I was able to use .position() with this!

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
$('.error').first().attr('id')
```

As stated in the other answers, using the css selector `:first` :

```
$('.error:first').attr('id')
```

Keep in mind that the result can be `undefined` if there is no id attribute or no element containing the class 'error'

Answer (score 2):

you can find it this way:

```
 $('.error:first').attr('id');
```

Answer (score 2):

This should be what you are looking for -

```
var className = 'error';
$('.' + className + ':first').attr('id');
```

I'm using the [`:first`](http://api.jquery.com/first-selector/) selector and the [`.attr()` function](http://api.jquery.com/attr/).

- `:first` - Selects the first matched element.
- `.attr()` -  Get the value of an attribute for the first element in the set of matched elements.

Looking at the definition of the `attr()` function, you might not even need to specify `:first`. However I find that it's always better to be as verbose as you can with selectors. This also improves readability.

Since you have multiple elements of different types with the same class (inputs and selects), I would also recommend specifying the type of element (in this case, an input) -

```
$('input.error:first').attr('id');
```

Comment: there is a typo: ':first')

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$(".error:first").prop('id');
```

**P.S.** As a suggestion, use `prop()`, if you are using jQuery 1.6+

The easiest way to see the difference between `.attr` and `.prop` is the following example:

```
<input blah="hello">
```

1. **`$('input').attr('blah')`**: returns `'hello'` as expected. No suprises here.
2. **`$('input').prop('blah')`**: returns `undefined` -- because it's trying to do `[HTMLInputElement].blah` -- and no such property on that DOM object exists. It only exists in the scope as an attribute of that element i.e. `[HTMLInputElement].getAttribute('blah')`

Answer (score 0):

```
var yourID = document.getElementsByClassName('error')[0].id;
```

Comment: `getElementByClassName` does not exists in js! but `getElementsByClassName` exist!

Answer (score -1):

you can use

```
$('input').first(function(){
    $(this).attr(id);
});
```

but this will work for all inputs
i suggest you wrap them in a div and write

```
$('div#%wrapper_id% input').first(function(){
    ...
}
```

Comment: `first` doesn't take a function as a parameter.  It just returns the first selected element.